# How to correctly set-up corrective bones influence?

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-GSNYkG69A&t=3856s) about the rigging of a skirt. I'm around 20:20, when the weight painting section begins and my file is behaving way differently that the one on the video.

Up until this point, I've made the exact same additional bones set-up as in the video, the only differences between my project and the tutorial being:

- my skirt object is part of a bigger manifold mesh including the whole body / tutorial's just a simple-sided skirt
- I parented the mesh to the armature via <kbd>crtl-P</kbd> with automatic weights / tutorial's through the modifiers tab
- my rigify rig is generated through MakeHuman's MPFB add-on / tutorial's probably custom

Now that I'm at the weight painting stage, the issues start piling up. When I'm selecting a bone from the additional set-up, it already has an influence on the mesh whereas the tutorial's got the untouched purple visual:
[image: mine on the left, tutorial's on the right]

After having selected a bone with no vertex group attach to it, I can paint but no new vertex group appears in the list whereas the tutorial show its automatic creation. Even when I select one of these new additional bones with their already established influence on the mesh, I can't find the vertex group attached to it in the list.
[image: mine on the left, tutorial's on the right]

When I apply weight paint to the mesh, an immediate transformation occurs whereas in the tutorial, the mesh doesn't move and simply store the information for future deformation. I suppose it has to do with the two issues already mentioned. I'm clearly changing the influence of one of the modifiers when I should be working on a brand new vertex group.
[image: mine on the left, tutorial's on the right]

Where could the difference be?

**EDIT**

My vertex groups were filtered through the "spine" keyword. Undid that, got my groups back. I was then able to find each groups associated with each bones and, if wanted, delete it to find myself back in front of the purple mesh. 2/3 solved.

**EDIT 2**

When I turn off the armature modifier, the mesh morphs a bit. I've unparented the mesh, deleted all its vertex groups then reparented it to the armature so it's clean. I don't understand how an armature modifier can deform the mesh right away as everything is in its default position.
[image]

You can get this Blender 4 file [here](https://we.tl/t-iLpipprDI6).

**FINAL EDIT**

When following the additional deform bones set-up in the tutorial, I missed the fact I was supposed to go back to edit mode to do resize the DEF-skirt bones (19:40). I resized them in pose mode and therefore, the armature wasn't in its rest position, hence issue 3/3 that is now solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm selecting a bone from the additional set-up, it already has
> an influence on the mesh whereas the tutorial's got the untouched
> purple visual:

You parented your mesh with automatic weights.  That created a vertex group for every deforming bone in the armature and created starter weights for that vertex group.  They did not do that (as you said.)

> After having selected a bone with no vertex group attach to it, I can
> paint but no new vertex group appears in the list whereas the tutorial
> show its automatic creation.

I'm confused, because you just wrote that your bones have influences on the mesh.  If you paint, and see colors change, there is a vertex group that you are painting.  Possibly it's the case that the vertex group already existed, so didn't need to be created, since you parented with automatic weights?  Possibly it's the case that new vertex groups are being created, but you don't see them because you're using a string to filter your list of vertex groups-- see below?

> Even when I select one of these new additional bones with their
> already established influence on the mesh, I can't find the vertex
> group attached to it in the list.

In the pic that immediately follows the quoted portion, you show us your vertex group list, where you are filtering by the text "spine".  Because of that filtering, Blender is only showing you vertex groups that contain that text.  Apparently, the vertex group on which you are painting does not contain that word.  Click on the x next to the filtering field to stop filtering by that text and to see all of your vertex groups.  (It's often wise to enable the display of names on your armature as well, so you can see in the 3D viewport exactly what bone, and thus what vertex group, you're painting.)

> When I apply weight paint to the mesh, an immediate transformation
> occurs whereas in the tutorial, the mesh doesn't move and simply store
> the information for future deformation.

This is probably because they have an unposed and unconstrained armature.  Your armature, however, may be posed, and definitely has constraints (I can see them, they make bones green.)  These constraints may alter the pose of bones even when you haven't given any bones any explicit constraints.  An armature from unposed (and unconstrained) bones will not change the mesh at all-- not when you are painting, and not any other time either.  If you would like to stop seeing these changes, you can either set the armature to rest position in properties/data/pose, or you can mute the armature modifier on your mesh object.  Either of these are temporary: when you want the armature to start working again, you re-enable pose position/armature modifier.

Comment: I feel so dumb! I did filter the vertex groups by "spine". Then I forgot about it.

Comment: I'm not surprised that the new bones have influence on the mesh since I parented with automatic weight. I don't understand why it's not the case in the video. Because I need all the other bones to be parented with automatic weights. Also, my armature IS in it's default position so I don't understand how the weight paint could deform the mesh at that point.

Comment: I unfiltered my vertex groups, got my groups back.
Now I'm able to locate each vertex group associated with each bone, delete it and get that purple mesh. So that's 2 issues on 3 solved. Great!
I'm still confused as to why the mesh is deforming under the weight paint. Armature is in its default pose, no weird modifiers are on.

Comment: Most likely, because you have bone constraints.  Read that part again.  A file would make it possible to verify that, as well as to demonstrate it.

Comment: I finally did mute the armature modifier. I've edited my question.

Comment: Your armature is not in its rest position.  Look at the scale of DEF-skirt_front.L .  As one example.  Like I said, put your armature in its explicit rest position by setting it to rest pose in properties/data/pose.  If you don't want weight painting to deform the mesh you're looking at.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. When I set up the additional DEF-bones, I didn't apply the scale of those bones. That's why the armature wasn't in its rest position. Thank you very much.

Comment: I mean "didn't go back to edit mode to resize them".